# ajax with offline cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, offline-caching

I am using the rack offline for offline method, but in one of my js file, i need to avoid the cache for one ajax call, because that same js using for offline and online. but after page reload that using the same cache when online? is there any other way to avoid that caching?

```
$('#cSearch').keyup(function(e){
  var number = $(this).val();
  var urlVal = "/customer/get_details";
  $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: urlVal,
      data: {"term": number, t: Math.random() },
      success: function(){
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a var to check if the system has connectivity to the web:

```
$('#cSearch').keyup(function(e){
  var number = $(this).val();
  var urlVal = "/customer/get_details";
  var cache = window.navigator.onLine ? false : true; // check if sys is online
  $.ajax({
      cache: cache, // <-----use it here
      url: urlVal,
      data: {"term": number, t: Math.random() },
      success: function(){
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @jai, but here the problem is, even if the cache is false, it takes from the cache, will not call the rails method. Also i have tried to add timestamp with url that also not working.

Comment: Got the issue, that was problem with request method